# MVC - Processing through larger JSON dataset in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am using a PHP script to loop through a larger JSON data set which has a structure like this:

```
"_embedded":{  
   "keyword":[  
      {  
         "_id":{  
            "$id":"570f7769767e582d008b511e"
         },
         "labels":[  
            {  
               "label":"Sample label",
               "category":"sample label category",
               "sport":"sample sport",
               "project":"core"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "_id":{  
            "$id":"570f77c8f2c2ce20008b5108"
         },
         "labels":[  
            {  
               "label":"Sample label 2",
               "category":"sample label category 2",
               "sport":"sample sport 2",
               "project":"core"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and here is my script in PHP

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$keywords = array();
$data = json_decode($result, true); // ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY

foreach($data["_embedded"]["keyword"] as $dataitem) {
    // GRAB NECESSARY MVC ITEMS
    $identifier = $dataitem->_id->$id;
    $label = $dataitem->labels[0]->label;

    // ADD TO KEYWORDS RESPONSE
    $keywords[] = array("id" => "$identifier", "label" => "$label");
}

$output = json_encode($keywords);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $output;
```

My problem is within my `foreach` loop as I am getting the appropriate JSON structure outputted but the values are all empty as below:

```
{
   "id": "",
   "label": ""
},
{
   "id": "",
   "label": ""
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing it as object, but it's array.
Try :

```
 $identifier = $dataitem['_id']['$id'];
 $label = $dataitem['labels'][0]['label'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try to access data with array as the data in json is coming as an array.

```
 $identifier  = $dataitem['_id']['$id'];
 $label = $dataitem['labels'][0]['label'];
```